# How to get the matched key from ngx translate?

Tags: ngx-translate, angular11

I have a directive that is sending a whole array of possible "fallback" keys to the Translate pipe's transform method (as the second param, "args"), and ngx somehow settles on the one that actually exists.  I know the Translate pipe has a 'lastKey' property, but that turns out to not have the right value if a fallback is chosen.

Is there a way to get what path it actually translated?